# Can you open iOS6 share sheet through an html url scheme?

Tags: html, ios, url, share

Just wondering if this possible through a url? Like you can open tweetbot by inputing:

```
tweetbot://post?message=hello%20world
```

Answer (score 0):

The share sheet is a modal view that will appear in your application—it’s not a separate application, which is what you use URL schemes for.